# Redirect back with anchor + flash message

Tags: laravel, session, redirect, anchor

I have a form like this in my footer:

```
<div id="footer">

    @if(Session::has('newsletter'))

    <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="newsletterSuccess">
        <strong>Gelukt!</strong> U bent toegevoegd aan onze email lijst.
    </div>

    @endif

    <form id="newsletterForm" action="/newsletter" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email adres" name="newsletterEmail" id="newsletterEmail" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

In my function in my controller I have:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    Mail::to('info@mydomain.be')->send(new News($request->all()));

    return redirect()->to(app('url')->previous(). '#footer')->with('newsletter', 'sent');
}
```

It redirects back to my previous page and to the correct anchor but it doesn't show my message. I've also tried this:

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#footer")->with('newsletter', 'sent');
```

But also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "hidden" class in your alert. try removing it.

```
<div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="newsletterSuccess">
    <strong>Gelukt!</strong> U bent toegevoegd aan onze email lijst.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withFlashSucess("Your message");
```

**OR**

```
return Redirect::to('your route',#footer')->withFlashSuccess("Your message");
```

**View file**

```
@if(Session::has('newsletter'))
    <div class="alert-success" id="newsletterSuccess">
        <strong>Gelukt!</strong> U bent toegevoegd aan onze email lijst.
    </div>
@endif
```